# The users in the Site Visitor's Groups are automatically being added to the Site Member's Group. Why?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharepoint-permissions, sharepoint-site

I am having the following problem - I have a SP site and I have a corresponding Site Visitor's Group (default one, created by SP). The Visitor`s Group has Read permissions. But when I add someone to it, that person is automatically being added to the Site Member's Group, which is giving him Edit permission. I have tried different approaches:

1. In that right hand-side panel, that appears when you click on "Site permissions", the people in question are at the same time in the Site visitors and in the Site members Group. Changing from "Edit" to "Read" in the Site members group or trying to remove them from it, removes them from the Site visitors group as well.
2. If I go to Advanced permission settings, the Site Members Group is actually empty. The people are to be seen in the Site Visitors Group.

Please help me, this is driving me mad!

Comment: Can you please check the permissions of user: https://sharepointmaven.com/2-ways-see-users-access-sharepoint/?

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, I did that and there it says "Read, Limited access". So no Edit permissions. But I still cannot understand why in the right hand-side panel, that appears when you click on "Site permissions", they have both Read AND Edit. It is confusing.

Comment: Are you adding the users directly in office 365 groups from SharePoint site? Try to add users from site permissions settings and not from site home page. (Go to Site Settings-->Site permissions (`https://siteUrl/_layouts/15/user.aspx`) --> Click on **Visitors** group --> Click on **New** --> then **Add Users** --> Add user names -->Share).

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, yes, tried that as well, same result.